# fraction**veryLargeNumber type math in EVM

Tags: evm

A fraction like 0.5**1/31556926, raised to an exponent in the range of 10^9. What are the best ways to do that in a smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

If exponent is integer (I assume exponent is time in seconds, right?), then I would recommend you to use this function from [ABDK Math 64.64](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.md): https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol#L327

Comment: Thanks. Yes, seconds. 64.64, do the numbers have to be formatted in a special format? To raise 2^4 for example, how would I format this?

return ABDKMath64x64.pow(2, 4)

Comment: Solidity does not offer any standard format for fractional numbers, so any format would be “special”.  This particular library uses simple fractions with 128-bit signed numerator and constant denominator: 2^64.  As long as denominator is constant, only numerator is passed/returned to/from functions.

Comment: To raise 2^4 for example, how would I format this, ABDKMath64x64.pow(2, 4)? If you show that then I'll figure it out more easily.

Comment: OK.  At first, you need to represent 2 as simple fraction with denominator 2^64.  This is quite simple: 2 = 2^65 / 2^64.  Now you need only the numerator of this fraction, i.e. 2^65.  Pass it to `pow` function as first argument: `pow (2^65, 4)`.  It will return you numerator of the result.  Divide returned value by 2^64 to get actual value.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I understand 64.64-bit fixed point numbers now, sort of. When trying with larger numbers close to what I need for the use-case I work on, 10^9 is the largest numbers I can feed into pow(fromUInt(number), exponent)). Does that sound about right?

Comment: Not quite right, as `fromUInt(number)` looks odd to me.  Function `fromUInt` converts integer into 64.64 fixed point, which does not make much sense here, as in original question you said you want to raise fractions to large powers, not integers.  Consider using `divi` or `divu` functions from the same library.  They allow converting arbitrary simple fractions into 64.64 fixed point format.